# Why would bolding the voltage symbol ⚡︎ display a decorative arrow ➫ instead (on the web, with system fonts)?

Tags: css, unicode, fonts, macos-high-sierra, system-font

This is kind of crazy… Here’s a GIF of me bolding the voltage symbol in Atlassian Confluence's wiki editor:

[image: Shows that bolding a symbol on Confluence changes the symbol]

It seems that bolding this symbol ⚡︎ results in the display of a completely different symbol (which looks like ➫) instead. I don’t think it actually changes it, because copying the arrow and pasting it elsewhere shows the same old voltage symbol.

Confluence's font stack appears to be `-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Noto Sans", Ubuntu, "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif`.

What is producing this result? It seems like the kind of thing that could happen with a bad web font, but that’s a system font stack.

It seems that Stack Overflow suffers the same exact problem:

Voltage symbol: ⚡︎
Voltage symbol, **bolded: ⚡︎**

And here’s what I see:

[image]

I’m browsing with Safari on OS X High Sierra 10.13.6. Notably, I cannot replicate this in e.g. the Notes app, even though that uses the system font (San Francisco).

Using Chrome just shows these missing-character symbols instead:

[image: chrome screen shot]

And things look just fine in Firefox:

[image]

What gives?

**Update (2018-08-03):** I just checked in Safari Technical Preview (their dev/preview release, similar to Chrome Canary), and this bug is no longer reproducible. Good, that means I don’t have to file a WebKit bug today.

**Update (2018-09-05):** I can no longer replicate in Safari  I suppose I am still curious what may have caused this bug, so I will leave the question open for any compelling theories or for an Apple engineer to confirm.

Comment: I'm afraid it's a problem with your setup. I see the two voltage signs in your example, although the second one doesn't appear bolded. What if you use a font that you know contains the voltage sign, does it still go wrong?

Comment: By the way, you have an U+FE0E character (variation selector 15) after the voltage sign. Is that by design?

Comment: @MrLister: OS X appended that code point itself when I selected the voltage symbol (to prevent it from becoming an emoji). It is not unwanted. See also: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nvdv5y4ecr581hw/Alan%20Hogan%20-%20How%20the%20Unicode%20Consortium%20Broke%20My%20Heavy%20Black%20Heart.mp4?dl=0

Comment: In the bolded text, I see a lightning bolt in IE11, Firefox, and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, @RemyLebeau. I was wondering what it was like on Windows. Are you on Windows 10?

Comment: @AlanH. Windows 7, actually. I also see the lightning bolt on Android as well.

Comment: Here on Linux, the bold one is actually bold in Chromium, but again, not bold in Firefox.